# SolrCloud - Best practices for number of shards

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Is there a good source of best practices on how to plan number of shards in a system to allow the system to grow while not creating too many shards unnecessarily ? 
Too many shards would add complexity and at some point may even hit performance

There were several questions about that matter in the past but with not a concrete suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As other articles prompt - it depends. Do sizing for a single shard according to your configuration, data, needs. Then you may estimate the number of shards necessary to store your data. When your data grows, you may add additional shards. See the (rather new) split API. Another option is to manage sharding by your own (implicit sharding), then you can be even more flexible.

Comment: Agree, its only try,try until u get what u want !